# undefined method `save' for 1:Fixnum

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, save, nomethoderror

I made some variables that is related to models and I want to save the new variable relating to the control structure, but I can't. It said "NoMethodError - undefined method `save' for 1:Fixnum:".

What I want to make is that the function if This program get 4 people, It will show the member name for that members. 5th member will be in the next group.

Anyone can solve this?

or if you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks

This is Waitinglists_controller

```
    class WaitinglistsController < ApplicationController
        before_action :authenticate

        def new
            @waitinglist = current_user.created_waitinglists.build
        end

        def create
            @waitinglist = current_user.created_waitinglists.build(waitinglist_params)
            if @waitinglist.save
                redirect_to waitinglist_waiting_path(@waitinglist, @owner)
            else
                render :new
            end
        end
    def waiting

        @group_number = Waitinglist.select(:count_number).last 
        @already_group_people = Waitinglist.where(count_number: @group_number).count
        @current_person_group_number = current_user.created_waitinglists.select(:count_number) 
        @current_group_people = Waitinglist.where(count_number: @current_person_group_number).count 

        case @already_group_people

        when 0
            @current_person_group_number = 1 
            @current_person_group_number.save 

        when 1..2 
            @current_person_group_number = @group_number 
            @current_person_group_number.save 

        when 3 
            @current_person_group_number = @group_number 
            @current_person_group_number.save　
            redirect_to show_waitinglist_path 

        when 4 
            group_number += 1 


            @current_person_group_number = @group_number 
                @current_person_group_number.save 
            end

    end

def show


    @current_person_group_number = current_user.created_waitinglist.select(:count_number)



        @matched_people = Waitinglist.find(count_number: @current_person_group_number)

        @matched_people == 0 if @matched_people = nil
    end 



    private

    def created_by?(user)
        return false unless user
        owner_id == user.id
    end

    def waitinglist_params
        params.require(:waitinglist).permit(:look_like, :id)
    end
end
```

This is Sessions controller for User loggin

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        user = User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def destroy
        reset_session
        redirect_to root_path
    end


end
```

Application contrtoller is this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception



  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

    private

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

    def logged_in?
        !!session[:user_id]
    end

    def authenticate
        return if logged_in?
        redirect_to root_path
    end

end
```

Under codes are for models

```
class Waitinglist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :waiting_person, class_name: 'User'
    after_initialize :init

    def init
      self.count_number  ||= 1           #will set the default value only if it's nil
    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :created_waitinglists, class_name: 'Waitinglist', foreign_key: :owner_id

    def self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
        provider = auth_hash[:provider]
        uid = auth_hash[:uid]
        name = auth_hash[:info][:name]
        image_url = auth_hash[:info][:image]

        User.find_or_create_by(provider: provider, uid: uid) do |user|
            user.nickname = name
            user.image_url = image_url
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I added all models and controllers. Im happy its gonna be useful for you to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the code you wrote makes very little sense and it is pretty hard to understand what you're trying to do here.

Firstly, you overuse instance variables. If you're not gona use them in another methods (it is hard to say as you haven't post rest of your class)

Secondly, you overuse `select` method.

```
@group_number = Waitinglist.select(:count_number).last
```

All it does is changing the SELECT statement when querying the database for models, but it still returns the model, not a number or field value. So `@group_number` is not a number - it is a WaitingList instance. If you want a number do:

```
group_number = WaitingList.last.count_number
```

(posting now as question may be closed in a second. Will update later if that won't happen)

You can only save the ActiveRecord objects, which means you need to have it somewhere. Apparantly you want to update `@current_person_group_number`, however you can't reassign this variable to do the trick. You have to get the whole model, change its attribute and then save the model. It would look sth like:

```
current_waiting_list = current_user.created_waitinglists.last    # This seems to be a collection, you need to tell here which waiting list you want to get from this collection
current_waiting_list.count_number += 1
current_waitin_list.save
```

My last point is - please look into act_as_list gem. Since you're creating waiting list it is a must have gem for you.

Comment: Thanks alot. That is all I need to know.And next time when I ask I"ll put more code as you said. @BroiSatse

Comment: Can you check my code again if possible? @BroiSatse

Answer (score 3):

It's quite clear to me. You call `save` on `@current_person_group_number`, which is instance of `Fixnum`, so it doesn't have `save` method defined.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer Marek. So How can I change @current_person_group_number? Just make it to local variable?

Comment: @MasanobuMizutani changing the scope of a variable doesn't change its type. You need to call `save` on an object that is an instance of a model class. You should fix your database access code and fetch the right objects.